# Find file names for executables, which are not used by other projects already

Tags: package-management, filenames, executable, development

A new program which should be deployed as package for the major distributions should avoid name clashes.

```
ls /usr/bin
```

can show me that `tail` is a bad choice for a new binary file name. But how can I get a list of all binaries which could be available on my system?

What is the best way to find out which file name for the executable binary is already used by other Linux packages already?

It is no problem, if the solution requires a special distribution.

Comment: @jimmij You are right. I just corrected my question. Now it should make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Google it.

There isn't really a better way. It could be that some other software by the same name exists but no distribution has gotten around to packaging it yet. And even that isn't fully reliable: someone else could be doing the same thing right this minute and conclude that the name is available just as you do.

You can check the package lists of major distributions, such as:

- Debian: `Contents-ARCH` files in [`debian/dists/unstable`](ftp://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/dists/unstable) (which you can search with `apt-file` on your Debian machine)
- Fedora: `HASH-filelist.xml.gz` in [`releases/VERSION/Fedora/ARCH/os/repodata/`](http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/i386/os/repodata/) (which you can search with `repoquery` on your Fedora machine)

Comment: The simplest way to do the same on Arch would be to use `pkgfile`.

Comment: @kyrias But what if one doesn't have Arch installed? For this question, it's useful to have information about distributions other than the installed one.

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to make a note of it just in case someone might wonder. The Arch repos doesn't contain a list of all files, though each repo has a [`files` file](ftp://ftp.archlinux.org/core/os/x86_64/core.files) which is a gzipped database. Searching those manually would be rather painful though so the easiest way would probably be to build `pkgfile` on your own distro and download the files DB, which also would be rather suboptimal. (Maybe a good project for me to make.)